# how I do In Realtime Database,if a child was matched than a sub child will be create, under the sub child the data will be stored,using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am making QR code scanner Form. In this form QR code scanner, date and a submit button are available. I create and save random number In my Realtime database and generate QR code of these random number. Now I try to do that when a QR code I scan If the data matched with the child which is in the database then under the child a sub child (named Filter_changed) will be create and under the sub child the date will be store.

My Database structure will be like this:

```
{
  All_Chassis:{
    chassis_No(random_number):{
      Filter_Change:{
          random_number: Date
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I try that and check the QR code with the database but the data does not store in the database.
My Code is:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics()
var db=firebase.database()



function onScanSuccess(qrCodeMessage) {
    //console.log(qrCodeMessage)
    
    document.getElementById('name').value = qrCodeMessage;


    db.ref('/All_Chassis').orderByKey().equalTo(qrCodeMessage).once("value", snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.exists()){
          const userData = snapshot.val();
          console.log("Found " , userData);
          document.getElementById('match').innerHTML = '<span class="result">'+"This Machine is verified from backend "+'</span>';
        }
        else{
            console.log("Not found");
            document.getElementById('match').innerHTML = '<span class="result1">'+"This Machine not found in backend "+'</span>';
        }
    });
  }
       
var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
      "reader", { fps: 10, qrbox: 150 });
  html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess, onScanError);

function submit (Date){
  document.getElementById('date').value = Date;

  db.ref('/All_Chassis').orderByKey().equalTo(qrCodeMessage).once("value", snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.exists()){
      onChildAdded(Filter_Change).push(Date);
      console.log("successfully stored");
    }
    else{
      console.log("Error occar");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What problem do you have with the code you shared? I.e. if you run in a debugger and step through it line-by-line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I try to write this code and check the QR code match with the database but the data does not store in the database.

Comment: It's more likely we can help if you tell us the **first** problem with the code, rather than the result you expected that didn't happen. So: **if you run in a debugger and step through it line-by-line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?**

Comment: the line function submit(date) is not work

Comment: Sorry @SANCHITACHOWDHURY, but "is not work" is really hard to help with. Unless somebody happens to spot the problem, we need you to tell us exactly what happens when you step through the code line by line in a debugger. That's what I'm trying to get from you here: a statement that says "the first time I see a problem is on line A, where I expect variable B to have value C, but it is D".